# Create and send PKCS10 in Windows 10 app

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate, uwp, csr

I am investigating how to create a PKCS#10 certificate signing request (CSR), send it to a Certificate Autority (CA), and create an X.509 client certificate based on the response from the CA. I want to do this in a Windows 10 application (so, an app built on UWP). Can i do this without an extra server to run the "CertCli 1.0 Type Library"?

The only info I've found is this: [MSDN Article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/07/31/programmatically-create-and-configure-a-client-certificate-for-use-in-your-windows-runtime-based-app.aspx)

It's for Windows 8.1, and it says that I need to have a server "between" the application and the CA, in order to send the CSR to the CA and create the actual certificate. Then I send this certificate back to the application. Deploying and running an extra server simply to host an API seems wasteful, so I'm trying to find another way.

- Is this still necessary in Windows 10?
- Could I package the "CertCli 1.0 Type Library" as a DLL or something along with my application?
- Are there open source alternatives (that will run in a UWP app) that can be used to handle the certificate and CSR instead?

Comment: More or less the problem is that with traditional certenroll approach the call is rpc, and universal apps run in the sandbox. So even if you find a way to code it, the sandbox won't let you execute. If you want to have an app that just looks like win 10, you can add the references to all the metro UI bits to WPF and then your app is a normal WPF and it can use all the normal components; the problem is, you won't be able to submit it to the store.